# How can I extract file extension from string?

Tags: regex, string, extract, looker-studio, re2

We have a custom field defined in data studio which extracts and returns the file extension from a string in this case it is from the event label.

I have been using the below with some success

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Label, '\\.([\\w\\.-]+)$')
```

However I'm finding if the string contains multiple periods its including that aswell

Eg it's also extracting text like

- 07.21.pdf
- 7.22.PDF
- 07.21.docx
- docx.pdf

How can I tweak my regex to only include from the last period and ignore any earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing `[\\w\\.-]` with `[^\\.]`

```
\\.([^\\.]+)$
```

`[^\\.]` will match everything except for `.`, so the match will not be able to contain dots inside.

The full formula would look like this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Label, '\\.([^\\.]+)$')
```